# How to update opengl modelview matrix with my own 4x4 matrix?

Tags: opengl, matrix, 3d, matrix-multiplication

I have 4x4 matrix for object's transformations.

```
float mat44[16];
```

But i don't know how to update OpenGL ModelView matrix using my matrix. should i use glTranslatef()/glRotatef() with relavant values from my matrix or should i use glLoadMatrix(),glMultMatrix() ? Pls help. Thanks.

Comment: What OpenGL version do you use?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to apply your transformation to current transformation already in OpenGL matrix stack, then you should write:

```
glMultMatrixf(mat44);
```

But if you want to discard what's currently on top of OpenGL matrix stack and use your own transformation, then you should write:

```
glLoadMatrixf(mat44);
```

Answer (score 2):

For OpenGL-2.1 and earlier use glLoadMatrix or glMultMatrix, depending on the task at hand.

For OpenGL-3 and later set them as the right uniform for your shader using one of the `glUniformMatrix` variants.